# Letting 'every process run until it is blocked' on an Erlang node

Tags: erlang

(Also available on [Erlang's mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-February/072574.html).)

Is it possible to write a function that waits for every process running on an Erlang node to reach a point where it is blocked, waiting for a message?

The function should return only when every process is waiting for a message that has not yet been sent to it. Assume that no process is in a time-related suspension (receive with an after clause, timer-related operations etc). The process running this function is, of course, excluded.

*Obviously wrong answer:*

`erlang:yield/0`: This gives a chance to every other process to run, but not necessarily until it is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

*Not 100% correct approach:*

```
only_one_not_waiting() ->
  Running =
    [P || P <- processes(), process_info(P, status) =/= {status, waiting}],
  length(Running) == 1
end.

everyone_blocked() ->
  case only_one_not_waiting() of
    true -> ok;
    false -> everyone_blocked()
  end.
```

Ignoring timers, running `only_one_not_waiting/0` repeatedly until it returns true (as `everyone_blocked/0` does) should indicate the desired system state, if this state is eventually reached.

However I am not sure how much trust one should put on the return value of `process_info(P, status)`.